# Vuejs App works in dev breaks in production -- build errors

Tags: vue.js, webpack, dependencies, production

My Vuejs app runs successfully in dev localhost but once I run the build command I get these difficult-to-debug errors. I deployed it successfully last week.

I'm assuming its my package.json file not containing the right dependencies so I copied that file from the successful build, deleted my node_modules folder and reinstalled -- no go.

## My Package.json

```
{
  "name": "client",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "A Vue.js project",
  "author": "-----------------",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "webpack-dev-server --inline --progress --config build/webpack.dev.conf.js",
    "start": "npm run dev",
    "lint": "eslint --ext .js,.vue src",
    "build": "node build/build.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.19",
    "@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons": "^5.9.0",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.9.0",
    "@fortawesome/vue-fontawesome": "^0.1.6",
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^5.2.2",
    "tiptap": "^1.14.0",
    "tiptap-extensions": "^1.14.0",
    "vue": "^2.5.2",
    "vue-headful": "^2.0.1",
    "vue-infinite-scroll": "^2.0.2",
    "vue-router": "^3.0.1",
    "vuetify": "^1.5.1",
    "vuex": "^3.1.0",
    "vuex-router-sync": "^5.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^7.1.2",
    "babel-core": "^6.22.1",
    "babel-eslint": "^8.2.1",
    "babel-helper-vue-jsx-merge-props": "^2.0.3",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.1",
    "babel-plugin-syntax-jsx": "^6.18.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "^6.22.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-vue-jsx": "^3.5.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.3.2",
    "babel-preset-stage-2": "^6.22.0",
    "chalk": "^2.0.1",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.1",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.0",
    "eslint": "^4.15.0",
    "eslint-config-standard": "^10.2.1",
    "eslint-friendly-formatter": "^3.0.0",
    "eslint-loader": "^1.7.1",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.7.0",
    "eslint-plugin-node": "^5.2.0",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "^3.4.0",
    "eslint-plugin-standard": "^3.0.1",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.0",
    "file-loader": "^1.1.4",
    "friendly-errors-webpack-plugin": "^1.6.1",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.30.1",
    "material-design-icons-iconfont": "^4.0.4",
    "node-notifier": "^5.1.2",
    "node-sass": "^4.11.0",
    "optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "ora": "^1.2.0",
    "portfinder": "^1.0.13",
    "postcss-import": "^11.0.0",
    "postcss-loader": "^2.0.8",
    "postcss-url": "^7.2.1",
    "rimraf": "^2.6.0",
    "sass-loader": "^7.1.0",
    "semver": "^5.3.0",
    "shelljs": "^0.7.6",
    "uglifyjs-webpack-plugin": "^1.1.1",
    "url-loader": "^1.1.2",
    "vue-loader": "^13.3.0",
    "vue-style-loader": "^3.0.1",
    "vue-svg-loader": "^0.12.0",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.5.2",
    "webpack": "^3.12.0",
    "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^2.9.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.2.3",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.9.7",
    "webpack-merge": "^4.1.0"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">= 6.0.0",
    "npm": ">= 3.0.0"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "> 1%",
    "last 2 versions",
    "not ie <= 8"
  ]
}
```

## The error message

```
 building for production...Error processing file: static/css/app.61609d17f4630a9d62a16c4312c20c20.css
(node:23459) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: CssSyntaxError: /Users/jon/Documents/Personal Projects/tmp/blog-site/client/static/css/app.61609d17f4630a9d62a16c4312c20c20.css:536:5: Unknown word
    at Input.error (/Users/jon/Documents/Personal Projects/tmp/blog-site/client/node_modules/optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin/node_modules/postcss/lib/input.js:130:16)
    at Parser.unknownWord (/Users/jon/Documents/Personal Projects/tmp/blog-site/client/node_modules/optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin/node_modules/postcss/lib/parser.js:563:22)
    at Parser.decl (/Users/jon/Documents/Personal Projects/tmp/blog-site/client/node_modules/optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin/node_modules/postcss/lib/parser.js:235:16)
    at Parser.other (/Users/jon/Documents/Personal Projects/tmp/blog-site/client/node_modules/optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin/node_modules/postcss/lib/parser.js:133:18)
    at Parser.parse (/Users/jon/Documents/Personal Projects/tmp/blog-site/client/node_modules/optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin/node_modules/postcss/lib/parser.js:77:16)
    at parse (/Users/jon/Documents/Personal Projects/tmp/blog-site/client/node_modules/optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin/node_modules/postcss/lib/parse.js:17:12)
    at new LazyResult (/Users/jon/Documents/Personal Projects/tmp/blog-site/client/node_modules/optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin/node_modules/postcss/lib/lazy-result.js:60:16)
    at Processor.<anonymous> (/Users/jon/Documents/Personal Projects/tmp/blog-site/client/node_modules/optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin/node_modules/postcss/lib/processor.js:138:12)
    at Processor.process (/Users/jon/Documents/Personal Projects/tmp/blog-site/client/node_modules/optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin/node_modules/postcss/lib/processor.js:117:23)
    at Function.creator.process (/Users/jon/Documents/Personal Projects/tmp/blog-site/client/node_modules/optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin/node_modules/postcss/lib/postcss.js:148:43)
    at OptimizeCssAssetsPlugin.processCss (/Users/jon/Documents/Personal Projects/tmp/blog-site/client/node_modules/optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin/index.js:63:19)
    at Object.processor (/Users/jon/Documents/Personal Projects/tmp/blog-site/client/node_modules/optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin/index.js:29:23)
    at /Users/jon/Documents/Personal Projects/tmp/blog-site/client/node_modules/last-call-webpack-plugin/index.js:139:8
    at arrayEach (/Users/jon/Documents/Personal Projects/tmp/blog-site/client/node_modules/lodash/_arrayEach.js:15:9)
    at forEach (/Users/jon/Documents/Personal Projects/tmp/blog-site/client/node_modules/lodash/forEach.js:38:10)
    at LastCallWebpackPlugin.process (/Users/jon/Documents/Personal Projects/tmp/blog-site/client/node_modules/last-call-webpack-plugin/index.js:136:3)
(node:23459) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 2)
(node:23459) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Comment: You have a CSS error on prod build. Make sure you use exactly the same modules & plugins, with the same settings, on both dev and prod (ref parsing CSS). You could also test uninstalling CSS related packages (i.e.: `"optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin"`).

Comment: Aright, thanks for the help. Going to compare prod to dev

Comment: Another way to go about this is to look directly on line `536` of `client/static/css/app.61609d17f4630a9d62a16c4312c20c20.css` and figure out what the CSS error is and fix it.

Answer (score 0):

**Problem**

I had comments in my .scss files that were syntactically incorrect:

`// this type of comment is for css files`

`/* this type of comment is for .scss files`

**Solution**

I removed the comments from the .scss files and ran the build -- worked perfectly.

Thanks again for offering your help.